# Why is dash autocomplete (super key) slow on first usage?

Tags: unity-dash, performance

I like the dash autocomplete feature (super/windows key) to open applications.

But the feature is slow. In 90% of all cases I open `keepass` or `pyCharm`.

But it takes several seconds to show the results on the first search after a reboot.

Why? It should be quite easy to use some sort of caching. The dash could remember the last N selected applications.

I have 80k images in 2k directories in my $HOME with this structure:

> images/YYYY/MM/DD

I guess that this is the reason, and not the internet connection.

I hear the hard disk heads spinning if I do the first search. The next searches are fast.

Comment: That's strange, dash is pretty fast here, applications and files are instantly refreshed. Online searches can take 2/3 seconds but that's it.

Comment: On my laptop it takes ~3 seconds if I type in "keep". I have launched keepass several times during the last days. This is far too slow for a common task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is only slow on my desktop computer where I have about 80k digital images.

I guess if you use the search for the first time after booting the search engine needs to load its index.

On other machines with much less files the search is fast.

This is just a guess, since I don't know which kind of database/index gets used by the dash search.

In my case it is not related to web searches.

Answer (score 2):

Dash can be slow, especially if the web scopes are on.
Try disabling the web scopes

```
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Lenses disabled-scopes "['more_suggestions-amazon.scope', 'more_suggestions-u1ms.scope', 'more_suggestions-populartracks.scope', 'music-musicstore.scope', 'more_suggestions-ebay.scope', 'more_suggestions-ubuntushop.scope', 'more_suggestions-skimlinks.scope']"
```

Now there is a better solution if you like opening applications using keystrokes then

- If the application are not too many, consider assigning shortcuts to them, you can add custom shortcuts in Ubuntu, open up ***Settings>Keybord>Shortcut tab>Custom Shortcut***
- Or if you want to open all the applications and places using keystrokes use the ***Synapse Launcher***, check this article [on webup8](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/11/syanpse-is-here-new-semantic-launcher.html)

Comment: Thank you, I executed the above command and rebooted. The first search for an application I started before the reboot still takes about 3 seconds. I think applications on `$PATH` should be found much faster.